# Custom list view onclick on item

Tags: android, listview

```
   holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");

          Intent i2 = new Intent(this,ImageSelection.class);
          startActivity(i2);      


        }
  });
```

This triggers.. But i cant call an Intent from here. Getting null pointer exception.. anybody has got the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to start another activity from your Custom `ListView` Adapter, right?

Than do this:

```
     Intent i2 = new Intent(mContext ,ImageSelection.class);
     mContext.startActivity(i2);
```

where `mContext` is the `Context` of the calling activity.

Comment: yes on adapter only. Let me try this dude

Comment: will accept it, says you cant accept within 6 minutes..

Answer (score 2):

*You are using `this` into listener then it will belongs to listener object. But you need `Context` object to declare the Intent.
So you need to change `this` with `YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this`.*

---

Change

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(this,ImageSelection.class);
startActivity(i2);
```

to

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,ImageSelection.class);
YOUR_ACTIVITY.this.startActivity(i2);
```

---

Ohh yes you are trying to start activity from adapter.

Then it should be

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(context_object_which_is_in_adapter, ImageSelection.class);
context_object_which_is_in_adapter.startActivity(i2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,ImageSelection.class);
YOUR_ACTIVITY.this.startActivity(i2);
```

**Best Wishes**